# Visual Studio 2017 - when debugging (Excel) Office Add-in the test file is made read-only

Tags: visual-studio-2017, office-js, office-addins

In Visual Studio 2017, when F5 debugging of Excel Add-in (Office-Js not VSTO), the workbook file being used to debug is marked as read-only...the read-only attribute is set in Windows 10 OS. This makes it impossible to save changes to the workbook while debugging.

Could be doing something wrong but it has happened on two separate dev PCs.  Does not happen on same PCs for Visual Studio 2015.

To repro, create new Excel Add-in in VS 2017.  In the add-in manifest project create a new Excel workbook. Add the workbook to the project and select it as the **Start Document** in project properties. F5 and see read-only attribute set in the OS on the workbook file.